# Connect case USB 2.0 to modern motherboard with no such header

Tags: usb, motherboard

I have a case which has some front panel USB 2.0 sockets and the usual 2.0 connector. It also has a front panel USB 3.1 Gen 1 socket with a separate 3.1 Gen 1 cord.

My motherboard, however, which is an ASUS WS C422 SAGE/10G only has 3.1 connectors. The front panel USB connector is labeled U31G2_E3 and has a 20-pin USB 3.1 Gen 2 female socket. The motherboard documentation says nothing about backwards compatibility.

The motherboard also has a USB 3.1 Gen 1 header. Documentation that came with the motherboard says that is DOES have backwards compatibility with 2.0. Currently, I have the 3.1 Gen 1 cord from the front of the case plugged into this header.

**So, the question is... how do I get the USB 2.0 in the front of the case connected to the motherboard?** I seem to have two options:

(1) Find some kind of adapter that will allow me to plug the USB 2.0 cord into the 3.1 Gen 2 header. This assumes that 3.1/2 is backwards compatible with USB 2.0 and that such an adapter exists.

(2) Unplug the 3.1/1 cord from the front of the case from the 3.1/1 header on the motherboard, plug in a 3.1/1 "module" (mentioned in motherboard manual) whatever that is, and that module will provide both a 3.1 and a 2.0 header on it maybe? I have not seen what this module looks like so I don't know.

Just so we are clear, on the left is what i have coming from the front panel, on the right is a 3.2 g1 motherboard header:

[image][image]

Comment: U31G2_E3 is backwards compatible to USB 2.0 You don't have to worry about anything at all. Install it as if you would use a USB 3 device, but then just plug in an USB 2.0 device. You did get a front panel with the mainboard containing a USB-A (and possibly USB-C) port, correct? See page 2-9 top right image.

Comment: USB 3 is simply USB2 with extra pins for the high speed signals. Both old and new pins work side by side. It is effectively USB2 + USB3 so dropping the USB3 just leaves USB2.

Comment: @DanielF I have added pictures so you can see the two connectors i am talking about. There is also a usb 3.1 G1 header, which is about twice the size of the G2 header but I currently have a different computer case cord plugged into that.

Answer (score 1):

Your right photo is U31G2_E3 (#10 in the manual).
Then there's also the U31G1_12 (#14 in the manual).

[image]

Option 1) Turns out that you can't do what you want to do; apparently it's an ASUS proprietary connector. So #10 cannot be used with a USB 2.0 front header. If your case does not have that connector and its corresponding front panel, you could buy one from ASUS. I think it's this one: https://www.asus.com/de/Motherboard-Accessories/USB-31-FRONT-PANEL/ (sorry for the German link, did not find it in US). If you use that front panel, you can connect USB 2.0 devices to it.

[image]

Option 2) What you could to is to use #14 with a cable adapter to use it with your existing USB 2.0 front panel. That would then be this cable https://www.amazon.de/dp/B00O0JGPK6/ (again, sorry for the German link)

[image]

Option 1+2) There exists the following adapter cable (https://www.amazon.de/dp/B077PNJNGJ/) which, from the looks of it, would turn #10 into a #14, but according to the product description it does not allow you to use USB 2.0 front panels. I believe that this is only due to the fact because the pins don't match in number, but after adapting this with the adapter mentioned above (chaining two adapters) it *might* work (no guarantees! could even fry your board, you know, 2020 is a really bad year).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

> (1) Find some kind of adapter that will allow me to plug the USB 2.0 cord into the 3.1 Gen 2 header. This assumes that 3.1/2 is backwards compatible with USB 2.0 and that such an adapter exists.

Yes, it should definitely be compatible as the cable literally goes straight to the USB Type-A ports, and you know *those* are compatible – you can always connect a 2.0 device to a 3.0/3.1 port and the other way around. As mentioned by others in the comments, USB 3.x only *adds* some extra pins to type-A ports, but it changes nothing about how the existing "2.0" pins behave.

So indeed there are adapters available, both for connecting a 2.0 panel to a 3.0 or 3.1 motherboard, and the other way around.

> (2) Unplug the 3.1/1 cord from the front of the case from the 3.1/1 header on the motherboard, plug in a 3.1/1 "module" (mentioned in motherboard manual) whatever that is, and that module will provide both a 3.1 and a 2.0 header on it maybe? I have not seen what this module looks like so I don't know.

This "module" sounds very much like a basic PCI-Express card with an additional USB 3.x controller on it. (Those often have direct ports on the back but also a 3.x header for front panel as well.) It is not motherboard-specific, just a standard PCIe device, and you can find plenty of those as well.